# Convert 2DArray to Array of Sets in Swift

Tags: swift

How does one convert a 2D array to an array of sets in Swift, without using NSArray or NSSet?

I would like to go from `[[UIView]]` to  `var convertedSetsArray: [Set<UIView>]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use something like this (assuming that views is an array of array of `UIView`s):

```
let result = views.map { Set($0) }
```

the type of views is `[[UIView]]`, the result is `Array<Set<UIView>>`, so you didn't use any "NS" related types.

Comment: I have an array of UIView arrays